# Problem in my latex references

Tags: bibtex

I used `LaTeX` to write my research and added references. I used the `Overleaf` website. The problem is that I noticed that the references do not appear in the order in which I added them. For example, the reference I added with number `1` appears in my document with the number [`22`]. I want references to appear in the order in which I added them.

Comment: if you use bibtex or biblatex the references are ordered according to the style that you specify (that is the main point of the programs) the usual orders are alphabetical based on author name or order of reference. the whole point is that you do not need to specify a number by hand. You can of course write the `thebibliography` list by hand, in whatever order you want, but that is usually less convenient.

Comment: Based on the fact that you've set the `bibtex` tag, I will assume that you use BibTeX to create the formatted bibliography. (Do please advise if this assumption is incorrect.) Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. The bibliography style is stated in the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please include a minimal working example with your question, so we can help you more easily. Also, the process of producing an MWE will often solve your problem before you ask.

Comment: @Mico I do use IEEEtran style